# how can i resize the images size in swiperjs

Tags: html, css, layout, swiper.js

My layout is no problem but I wanna adjust the size of the image,
I tried to make images set to width: 1130px but cannot responsive...
how to fix it.

My Swiper code:

```
new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    centeredSlides: true,
    spaceBetween: 10,
    loop: true,
    pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        clickable: true,
    },
    navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
    breakpoints: {
        1400: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
        },
        640: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
        },
        320: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
        }
    }
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnbtI.png)

Answer (score 0):

Don't set fixed width for images. Better, insert `img` in `div` and set to `img` following properties:

```
width: 100%;
display: block;
```

Therefore, if you change width of layout or div, images width will fit to parent.
Images always should have full width for responsive view.